# Need to resize my JTextArea where some content is already present

Tags: java, resize, mouse, jtextarea

I want to resize my jtextarea with mouse dragging at the corners of the jtextarea. right now i just have a jtextarea where some content is already there, but i want to use the resizable with mouse option to view my already present content in a bigger jtextarea. Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Place the JTextArea in a layout which resizes the JTextArea when the container itself is resized.  For example, place it in a JScrollPane in the center of a BorderLayout.

Comment: i did include the jscrollpane in the center of the border.layout but it is not resizing according to the window size. do not know why?

Comment: Edit your question to include your code which builds your window.